# Data structure for finding lowest element in range

Tags: data-structures

Consider the following setting: There are tasks $T = \{T_i\}_{i=1}^n$ with priorities $p_i$, and locations $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Given a location $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, I would like to find and pop the task with the highest $p_i$ in an $L_\infty$ ball of radius $r$ centered at $y$. What are some data structures that might make this more efficient?

One could use a ball tree to get efficient range queries, but then you have to iterate over all the tasks in range since they won't be sorted by priority. You could also maintain a sorted list of tasks, but then you might need to iterate over all of them if no tasks are in range of the query.

Answer (score 1):

A plausible data structure might be a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), where you augment each internal node with the priority of the highest-priority task contained within that region.  This will let you do a best-first search, i.e., search first in regions that contain high-priority tasks, and avoid recursing into any region whose highest-priority task is of a lower priority than the best task found so far.

To elaborate a bit more, if $x$ is a tree node, let $p(x)$ denote the priority field associated with $x$ (i.e., the priority of the highest-priority task in the region associated with $x$).  Note that $x$ has four children, let's call them $y_1,\dots,y_4$.  Suppose we discover that the highest-priority task is under $x$, and we want to pop (delete) that task.  Then this task must be under one of $y_1,\dots,y_4$, say $y_i$.  Now we recursively pop (delete) that task from $y_i$, update $p(y_i)$, and then we can update $p(x)$ using the relation

$$p(x) = \max(p(y_1),\dots,p(y_4)).$$

Thus updating $p(x)$ can be done in $O(1)$ time.  In the end, we do one update per node along the path from the root to the highest-priority task.  This means that the cost to update all of the priority fields in the tree is at most the cost to search the tree to find the highest-priority task.

Comment: Is the best way to do so to keep a heap at each internal node?

Comment: @DavisYoshida, there is no need for a heap at each internal node, just a single field that contains the value of the highest priority of all tasks underneath it (this can be computed bottom-up in linear time, and when you delete entries, it is easy to update it).

Comment: I'd rather do better than linear time on deletion. In case it wasn't clear, the fundamental operation isn't just to find the minimum, but also delete it.

Comment: @DavisYoshida, deletion doesn't require linear time; deletion is just as fast as search.  See edited answer.

Comment: Ah gotcha. Thanks!